# Format value in text input to currency

Tags: javascript, input, text, currency

I have made a small calculator, where I want the sum in to be displayed with the format currency in the readonly input text.
Since I'm new to javascript (and this forum), I can't get it to work.
Thought my code below would work. Can anyone give me some pointers on how to make it work?

```
<h2>Calculator/h2>

<input
  type="text"
  id="number1"
  value="0"
  onchange="summa.value = (number1.value*1) + (number2.value*1)"
/>

<br>

<input
  type="text"
  id="number2"
  value="0"
  onchange="summa.value = (number1.value*1) + (number2.value*1)"
/>

<br/><br/>

<input
  type="text"
  readonly="readonly"
  id="summa"
  value="0"
  onchange="this.value.toLocaleString("sv-SE", {
    style:"currency", 
    currency:"SEK",
    currencyDisplay:"symbol",
    maximumFractionDigits: 0
  });"
/>
```

Comment: You should always format your code
It helps us read it better
Read this to learn more on [how to format code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Thanks! Now I know how to do that :-)

Comment: Quite a few typos, but also programatic changes to an input don't trigger an `on change`  event. It will be far clearer to abstract your methods into its own script and then appropriately update the total.

Answer (score 1):

Your code as posted shows quite a few typos, but the main reason it 'doesn't work' is that programatic changes to an input don't trigger a [`change event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event). It will be far clearer to abstract your methods into its own script and then appropriately handle the changes and update the total.

Here is a minimal example of your logic abstracted into html and a separate script. The inputs have been changed to [`type="number"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) to avoid entering non-numeric values. The script then queries the three inputs using [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) and attaches `change` listeners to the two accepting input using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Finally there is a single function declared to update the value of the third input with the formatted value.

```js
const number1 = document.getElementById('number1');
const number2 = document.getElementById('number2');
const summa = document.getElementById('summa');

function updateTotal() {
  const total = Number(number1.value) + Number(number2.value);
  summa.value = total.toLocaleString('sv-SE', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'SEK',
    currencyDisplay: 'symbol',
    maximumFractionDigits: 0,
  });
}

number1.addEventListener('change', updateTotal);
number2.addEventListener('change', updateTotal);
```

```html
<h2>Calculator</h2>

<input type="number" id="number1" value="0"/>
<br />
<input type="number" id="number2" value="0" />
<br />
<input type="text"  id="summa" readonly="true" value="0"/>
```

*note: your method of coercing a string to number is valid, but there are more transparent methods. Here I'm using the [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/Number) constructor directly but there are [plenty of other methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-to-convert-a-string-to-an-integer-in-javascript)*

---

If you somehow feel that you *need* to do this all inline you can apply the same logic, but you'll instantly note the amount of duplicated code.

```html
<h2>Calculator</h2>

<input type="number" id="number1" value="0" onchange="summa.value = (Number(number1.value) + Number(number2.value)).toLocaleString('sv-SE', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'SEK',
    currencyDisplay: 'symbol',
    maximumFractionDigits: 0,
});" />
<br />

<input type="number" id="number2" value="0" onchange="summa.value = (Number(number1.value) + Number(number2.value)).toLocaleString('sv-SE', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'SEK',
    currencyDisplay: 'symbol',
    maximumFractionDigits: 0,
});" />
<br />

<input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="summa" value="0" />
```

Alternatively you can include an inline script as a decent compromise.

```html
<h2>Calculator</h2>

<input type="number" id="number1" value="0" />
<br />
<input type="number" id="number2" value="0" />
<br />
<input type="text" id="summa" readonly="true" value="0" />

<script type="module">
  const number1 = document.getElementById('number1');
  const number2 = document.getElementById('number2');
  const summa = document.getElementById('summa');

  function updateTotal() {
    const total = Number(number1.value) + Number(number2.value);
    summa.value = total.toLocaleString('sv-SE', {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'SEK',
      currencyDisplay: 'symbol',
      maximumFractionDigits: 0,
   });
  }

  number1.addEventListener('change', updateTotal);
  number2.addEventListener('change', updateTotal);
</script>
```

Comment: Up vote, though I do wonder how this works when the country code is set to El Salvador (sv) and the currency is in Swedish krona (SEK).

Comment: `sv-SE` is [Swedish (Sweden)](https://www.localeplanet.com/icu/sv-SE/index.html) confusion with `es-SV` [Spanish (El Salvador)](https://www.localeplanet.com/icu/es-SV/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, you are correct.  toLocaleString expects an [ISO-639](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13214_01/wli/docs92/xref/xqisocodes.html#wp1252447) language code and not an [ISO-3166](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13214_01/wli/docs92/xref/xqisocodes.html#wp1250799) country code.